# Sitebricks JSON default serializer. And why does it return text/json instead of application/json

Tags: java, json, serialization, content-type, sitebricks

Hmm...I intended on asking only one question. But I've instead decided to *kill two birds with one stone*.

**First Question**: What does Sitebricks use as the default serializer/deserializer between Java POJOs and JSON? For example, let's say that this is my POJO:

```
public class MyObject {
    private String key;
    private int value;
    public MyObject (String k, int v) {
        this.key = k;
        this.value = v;
    }
}
```

And this is an example of a method in my Sitebricks servlet:

```
@Get
public Reply<?> listPools() {
    return Reply.with(new MyObject("Foo", 6)).as(Json.class);
}
```

I did not annotate `MyObject` with any **Jackson** annotations, nor did I use **GSON** anywhere in my code. Yet, much to my surprise, I get back this as my content body in the response:

```
{"value":6,"key":"Foo"}
```

So what I would like to know is what technology or framework or what-not that Sitebricks is using by default to serialize-deserialize JSON. Jackson? GSON? Witchcraft and wizardry?

Now the **Second Question**. I noticed in the header that the response *Content-Type* was `text/json`. This looked weird to me because, in my past experience, I've always dealt with `application/json` as the Content-Type for JSON. This [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type) confirms my belief. Any comments on this point?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Err...crap sorry, disregard the first question if you wish. I should've read [this Sitebricks.org page](http://sitebricks.org/#requestandreply) more carefully. *"Json.class - Jackson based Json transport"*. Second question is still up for grabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And it's still possible to change it on the go with the following

```
 return Reply.with(...).as(Json.class).type("application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

Answer (score 1):

Sitebricks uses Jackson by default which will convert objects without any configuration using sensible defaults. If you want to override the behavior, bind an ObjectMapper using standard Jackson-prescribed config.

You should probably set application/json for most cases, correct. SB should set this, you're right, I'll make the change in trunk.

Comment: Actually SB already uses "application/json" for the Json transport. Please build from source for the latest (it's really easy, just clone & mvn install)

Comment: Any plans to release this code onto the Maven central repository?

Comment: This is now released as part of 0.8.7. Latest (nightly) Sitebricks snapshots are now available in Sonatype's OSS repository too.